# How can I add a sitemap to google code hosting?

Tags: sitemap, google-code

I have a project hosted in google code.
I'd like to upload a sitemap. Is it possible? How?
I have managed to create a sitemap.xml file, but it seems google code doesn't give me a way to upload it.
Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible. Sitemaps are not for Google code.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway: given the announced shutdown of google code, I'm moving my project to sourceforge :-)